# Count and Group by 2 different columns SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have below table and want to find out a count and group by that will show the number of times republic of ireland played a particular opponent regardless if they are the home team or away team

[image: table]

I want something that will show like the below

```
OPPONENT TIMES PLAYED            
SCOTLAND       2    
UKRAINE        2    
ARMENIA        2    
LITHUANIA      1
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does the table include matches that don't have republic of ireland?

Comment: nope only republic of ireland for this test case

Comment: If you know it is only that string there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Any other suggestions rather than a UNION ALL? @hogan TY

Comment: I edited my answer -- I don't think this is the best way to do it, but it shows you how.  Remember you can also up-vote my answer if you think it is a good one.

Comment: @Hogan once I get 15 reputation points I will be sure to! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it -- normalize the table with a UNION ALL and then group by and count

```
 SELECT sub.team_b, count(*) as times_played
 FROM (
   SELEECT home_team as team_a, away_team as team_b 
   FROM table
   WHERE home_team = 'Republic of Ireland'
   UNION ALL
   SELEECT away_team as team_a, home_team as team_b 
   FROM table
   WHERE away_team = 'Republic of Ireland'
 ) AS sub
 GROUP BY sub.team_b
```

---

If you know that every record has 'Republic of Ireland' as one of the teams, then you don't need to check if it exists only which is which like this:

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN home_team = '' 
             THEN home_team 
             ELSE away_team 
        END as OPPONENT, count(*) as times_played
 FROM table
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN home_team = '' THEN home_team ELSE away_team END
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I thought it was able to happen with just a SELECT statement but this works perfect. Time to brush up on my UNION knowledge!

Comment: One question? What is the purpose of ‘sub’ in the above query? Thx

Comment: @DarraghO'Dowd -- that is an alias for the "name" of the sub select. so it could say sub.team_b in the select statement.  I will change it to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT target_col, count(*) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT 
     if (home_team = 'Republic of Ireland', away_team, home_team) AS target_col
    FROM table
    ) tb
GROUP BY target_col
```

Comment: if is not something that exists in SQL

Comment: Are you sure? There is this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp

Comment: That is only mysql and it is different that EVERY OTHER SQL implementation and the standards.  Look up SQL CASE in google.